# Definition of limit: Heine implies Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $E$ be a metric space, $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\bar{x} \in \text{cl}(E)$. We say that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \bar{x}} f(x) = L$  if:

*Heine's definition*: for any sequence $x_n \rightarrow \bar{x}$ and for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(x_n)-L|<\epsilon$ for any $n>N$;

*Cauchy's definition*: for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $\text{d}(x,\bar{x})<\delta$.

How can I prove that Heine's definition implies Cauchy's?

Comment: It is called Heine's criterion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to prove that (not Cauchy) implies (not Heine): Assume the Cauchy criterion is not satisfied at $x$. Then there is $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta=1/n$, $n\in \mathbb N$, there is $x_n$ with $d(x,x_n)<\delta$ and $|f(x_n)-L|>\epsilon$. Now Heine's criterion is not fulfilled, since $x_n\to x$ but $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $L$.

Comment: Not Heine means that there exists a sequence $x_n \rightarrow \bar{x}$ and an $\epsilon >0$ such that $|f(x_n)-L|>\epsilon$ for any $n$?

Comment: Heine is equivalent to: for all sequences $(x_n)$ with $x_n\to x$ it holds $f(x_n)\to L$. Not Heine: there is a sequence $x_n\to x$ such that $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $L$.

Comment: Why is there an $x_n$ such that $d(x, x_n) <\delta$?

Comment: Why not? This is just the negation of the statement.